# Remote Desktop Raspberry Pi

Tags: remote, desktop

Is it possible to use a remote desktop connection to a raspberry Pi from another Raspberry Pi?

If so, how?

Comment: Depending on what you really need, running `ssh -Y user@rpi2` from `rpi1` could be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could attempt to use the inbuilt `ssh` command in your terminal emulator if ssh server is enabled on the other PI; you can enable it on a headless PI by putting a file with no extension in the boot partition on the SD card.

If you require a graphical desktop use `sudo raspi-config` in the remote ssh connection and enable `vnc server`. Than on the original PI open VNC viewer (it comes pre-installed) and connect similarly to how you would using `ssh`. VNC will not work on raspbian lite due to a lack of a graphical desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install a VNC server. TightVNC is a good choice. AdaFruit has a great tutorial:

[VNC Remote Control- Raspbian](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-7-remote-control-with-vnc)

You can then use the installed VNC client to connect.

You can always install TeamViewer as a quick and dirty solution as well

[TeamViewer Raspian ARM](https://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/teamviewer-automatic-download/?package=teamviewer-host_armhf&extension=deb&packageOS=linux)